# Using python global variables with celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have a `celery task` that takes a certain argument `arg`, something like this.

```
@shared_task
def some_function(arg):
    task_1()
    task_2()
    task_3()

@shared_task
def task_1()

@shared_task
def task_2()

@shared_task
def task_3()
```

This get called withing some code like this

`tasks.some_function.delay(arg)`

Now, `task_1, task_2 and task_3` need the argument. I could pass the argument to the function but, each time I wanted to add an argument for example (Which is my problem right now), I'd need to re-write the function definition of each task so they can accept this new argument.

How can I define a global variable in a way that I can use this new `arg` inside each task after the `.delay()` is called.
Will each `.delay()` call have its own "instance" of the global variable?

In the future the idea is to use some object oriented approach, but a quick "patch" is needed at the moment.

Comment: Bad idea. If you think you will change arguments so often, then simply use a single dictionary as your arg. You can alter the structure of that dictionary whenever you like...

Comment: Maybe you can pass the function you re-write as args.
I don't think that is good idea, but you can try it.